# Behavior of events, and the $event variable in Vue.js

Tags: events, vue.js, arguments

With the following method "updateCoords", it is necessary to provide the 'event' argument.  The following div tracks the mousemove event and updates the cursors x and y coordinates in real time via methods.

```
<div id="content">
  <div @mousemove="updateCoords($event)" style="height:400px;width:400px;border:2px solid black;">
    {{x}} {{y}}
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    methods: {
      updateCoords: function(event){
      this.x = event.clientX;
      this.y = event.clientY;
     }
    }
  })
</script>
```

This function does not work if event is not passed.  It makes sense to me that we would pass something here since X and Y coordinates are dependent on the last location of the event.  But how is this data stored?  Do events track and store data within themselves?

Also it seems to make no difference if I pass my method the special $event variable or not.  Calling...

```
  @mousemove="updateCoords($event)"
//is the same as 
  @mousemove="updateCoords()"
```

Does view automatically know that an incoming event argument is $event?  Or is $event important to use in some other particular case??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, handlers receive the `$event` as their argument. You can use
[methods in inline handlers](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Methods-in-Inline-Handlers), in which case, if you want `$event` to be one of the arguments, you need to include it.